# Possible to abort reboot on Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora-15

**Is it possible to abort reboot on Linux machine.My fedora machine takes 10-15 sec to reboot.**

My concern is can i stop it?

for shutdown i could find **shutdown -c** will abort is there any similar command to stop for reboot.

Comment: I know `shutdown -c` aborts *pending* shutdown, i.e. when the time was not `now` nor `+0`, and it's not up yet. `reboot` should be basically `shutdown -r`, so `shutdown -c` should work as well. But again: when it's *pending*. It seems to me you want to abort when it's already *in progress* (tasks are being killed etc.). Please clarify.

Comment: when i excute reboot on my terminal its goes  with in 10-15 sec for reboot .So in between i want it to abort ie. cancel and make it in operating state